# Passing index value in append function in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a chat box in angular, I made it some how but I feel the code is wrong when I click the members it show different member. Please someone correct the code here the link to `Plunker`[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/TzPY1WNov1JiPGtoMccS?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$index` will give you the index of the ordered item in UI(After Applying `ngRepeat` and `orderBy`) not in the index of the item in the data array. To elaborate this behavior, When I select the artist name "Hassum Harrod" the `$index` will return me the value as 2 but the same data is available at the `index` 3 from your data.json. You can pass the item itself to your `AppendText(item)`  . I have modified your [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/j6jHiz?p=preview).

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, it's really helpful.